# elastic search terms query: is it possible to fetch 1 document of each terms input?

Tags: elasticsearch

Query1: To get 1 document with field "user" = "kimchy".

```
    GET /_search
    {
        "from" : 0, "size" : 1,
        "query" : {
            "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
        }
    }
```

Query2: To get 1 document with field "user" = "elasticsearch".

```
    GET /_search
    {
        "from" : 0, "size" : 1,
        "query" : {
            "term" : { "user" : "elasticsearch" }
        }
    }
```

Query3: To get 2 document with field "user" either = "kimchy" or "elasticsearch".

```
    GET /_search
    {
        "from" : 0, "size" : 2,
        "query": {
        "constant_score" : {
            "filter" : {
                "terms" : { "user" : ["kimchy", "elasticsearch"]}
                }
             }
         } 
    }
```

The problem in Query3 is that multiple documents can have "user" as "kimchy" OR "elasticsearch" and in 3rd query we might get both the documents with user "kimchy" OR Both documents with user "elasticsearch". How can we modify this terms query or write other query to fetch 1 document with "user" = "kimchy" and another document with user = "elasticsearch".

One solution is to hit multisearch query with Query1,2. But is there any other way to solve this i.e. fetching one document of each "terms" inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is another way, by using a mix of `terms` and `top_hits` aggregation, like this:

```
GET /_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "user": [
            "kimchy",
            "elasticsearch"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "users": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sample": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": {
              "_script": {
                "script": {
                  "source": "(doc._id.value + salt).hashCode()",
                  "params": {
                    "salt": "some_random_string"
                  }
                },
                "type": "number",
                "order": "asc"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For each user `kimchy` and `elasticsearch`, you'll get one document that matches.

Comment: I need to pick random "user" and not always the same user with top_relevance. Is it possible OR this query would return back same "kimchy", "elasticsearch" document everytime?

Comment: `top_hits` also accepts a `sort` setting, where you can use a script which does random sorting.

Comment: everything else is fine, but i don't get results back when I am including the "sort" part in query. Could you please check if you are getting results back with this sort query?